# vxprint failed with "No such disk group" error

Tags: storage, solaris, solaris-10, veritas-cluster-server

I have a NETRA machine with solaris 10 with EMC storage. During cluster installation the installation failed, and from the log files I see the following error which I don't understand:

```
/usr/sbin/vxprint -q -g ov-dg -d c2t0d0
VxVM vxprint ERROR V-5-1-582 Disk group ov-dg: No such disk group
```

Comment: Do you have a disk group called ov-dg ? `vxdg list` should show you this.

Comment: I get this  --> [root@solaris /]# vxdg list
NAME         STATE           ID

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have any dgs.

Comment: this mean that I not see the storage disks?

Comment: @yael I'm sorry if this sounds rude but you're clearly not skilled enough yet to be doing your job, why are you struggling on your own with this, is there nobody to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you don't have `ov-dg` (or any vx disk groups) configured on your Solaris host.